# CPanel / WHM // CentOS // SELinux

Tags: centos, cpanel

The file config indicates SELinux mode is "target".
Is it enabled or disabled ?

Terminal/SSH says 'disabled'.
But several behaviours here and there act like it is enabled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is enabled, but only targeted network services are protected.

From the config file `/etc/selinux/config`:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
# strict - Full SELinux protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

You can also type `getenforce` and it will show you if SELinux is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

cPanel & WHM to run on your server, SELinux must remain disabled. you can check selinux status through below command.

```
sestatus
```